# Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So, I am using `OS X  El Capitan` with  `Eclipse (Neo) and Python`.  I am wrote some Python with Selenium scripts.

These scripts were working fine.

Then I upgraded from `OSX Sierra` to `El Capitan`

> **Note:** this is about the only major change
>   that I did to my setup.

When I tried to run the same scripts, now, I get the

> **Message:** chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH

As far I can tell chromedriver IS on my PATH.

Now, I can only make my scripts work if I `hard copy` the path to my chrome driver, which is not the most elegant way to do things, as we all know.

Has anyone else has/had this issue?  Thoughts on any configuration with my `Eclipse + Python`.

[My Eclipse and Python project screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3H5e.png)

[my PYTHONPATH screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtXsb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about python. But the implementation for the webdriver should be same irrespective of the language. Here you have called the chrome webdriver, but have you defined the path for chromedriver.exe in you code? For example, in java it looks like this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-java-3.4.0/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The error you are getting is referring to the chromedriver.exe not the python environment.

Python Solution from Google documentation:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all verify your driver path , if you open a command prompt and type in chromedriver  and hit Enter. If you get message "Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 .." your path is correctly set up.
In python, alternate solution is you can use
`driver = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_driver/chromedriver.exe")`
 Hope this should work !

Comment: Thanks Dhruv!!!  I think that I had seen these checks & solutions.
And indeed my OS/System PATH is set correctly because in a Terminal when I type "chromedriver" it launches like you said.

And like I mentioned in my original question doing a "hard copy" of the path, like you suggested, also works.

BUT this still leaves my question why I can't seem to be able to configure Eclipse to see my PATH, though I had setup PYTHONPATH as shown on my screen shots above, "to include the directory where my chromedriver was installed"

Comment: I do not have idea about mac os directory, but in windows it works like add **'chromedriver.exe'**  in 'C:\Python27\Scripts' (see in your case and change accordingly )and then you need not to provide the path of driver, just use     'driver= webdriver.Chrome()'